# Blogger widget templates

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I am trying to use bootstrap css in Blogger but I can't see how to retrieve post titles and bodies with widgets and b tags.

I found this tutorial http://thoughtsomething.blogspot.it/2009/01/understanding-blogger-template-1.html

But it does not provide an example of it.
It seems so hard but it can't be so I guess I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Layouts Data Tags](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47270) page on Google Support might help you out.

This page helped me a lot when I was modifying my Blogger template as it contains:

> a master list of all such available data. It is divided into sections
>   by page element, because different types of widgets use different
>   data.

Comment: Thanks I finally realized tumblr provides a simpler (at least to me) template language, still open to customizations and to any kind of ads